# Can't delegate methods within closure implicitly even with DELEGATE_FIRST/DELEGATE_ONLY resolve strategy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a method which extends all domain classes:

```
static def bindGormStaticApiExtensions() {
    Holders.grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { domainClass ->
        domainClass.metaClass.static.withDataSource = { DataSource ds, Closure callable ->
            HibernateDatastore datastore = Holders.applicationContext.getBean(HibernateDatastore)
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = datastore.sessionFactory
            Session session = null
            Connection connection = null
            try {
                SessionBuilder sb = sessionFactory.withOptions()
                connection = ds.getConnection()
                session = sb.connection(connection).openSession()
                callable.delegate = delegate
                callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
                return callable?.call(session)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("An error occured", e)
            } finally {
                session?.close()
                if(connection && !connection.closed) {
                    connection.close()
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

However when I call this method on a domain class, I have to use `delegate.findByXXX()` otherwise groovy uses `owner` even though I've explicitly set the closure resolve strategy to `DELEGATE_FIRST`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't reproduce your problem. It worked fine when I simulated it. Have you tried rehydrate()? `callable.rehydrate(delegate, delegate, delegate).call(session)`

Comment: I tried calling rehydrate and in debug I've verified that `owner`, `delegate` and `thisObject` are all set to the domain class, however when the closure is run I still get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.example.package.MyService$_myServiceMethod_closure4.findBySomething() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [something]`. The Invocation looks like this `DomainClass.withDataSource(ds) { findBySomething(somePropertyFromOuterScope) }`.

Comment: In my experimentation, I noticed that it's the dynamic finders that are not working. For example `list()` works fine. Is that the case for you too, @MrPlow?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Yeah, `list()` seems to work fine. A bug in Groovy possibly?

Comment: No not in Groovy. Groovy doesn't support methodMissing for static method calls. It's added by Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, the problem is in Groovy. Here's a simple test which demonstrates the problem:

```
assert MyClass.thisMethodDoesNotExist() == 'You called static method thisMethodDoesNotExist'
assert new MyClass().thisMethodDoesNotExist() == 'You called instance method thisMethodDoesNotExist'

new MyClass().with {
    assert thisMethodDoesNotExistEither() == 'You called instance method thisMethodDoesNotExistEither'
}

MyClass.with {
    // The following method call will throw a groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
    assert thisMethodDoesNotExistEither() == 'You called static method thisMethodDoesNotExistEither'
}

class MyClass {
    static Object $static_methodMissing(String name, Object args) {
        "You called static method $name"
    }

    Object methodMissing(String name, Object args) {
        "You called instance method $name"
    }
}
```

The stackstrace looks like this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript10.thisMethodDoesNotExistEither() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at ConsoleScript10$_run_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript10:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.with(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:241)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$757.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at ConsoleScript10.run(ConsoleScript10:8)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:524)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:503)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:170)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy:980)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have my suspicions, I don't have a full understanding of Groovy's MOP implementation, so I don't know how to fix this issue. There's an open [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6644) that reflects this problem.

### Work-around

Good news! There's a work-around for this problem. And it's super simple: instead of using a class as the delegate for the closure, use an
instance which wraps the class; a proxy.

```
static def bindGormStaticApiExtensions() {
    Holders.grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { domainClass ->
        domainClass.metaClass.static.withDataSource = { DataSource ds, Closure callable ->
            HibernateDatastore datastore = Holders.applicationContext.getBean(HibernateDatastore)
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = datastore.sessionFactory
            Session session = null
            Connection connection = null
            try {
                SessionBuilder sb = sessionFactory.withOptions()
                connection = ds.getConnection()
                session = sb.connection(connection).openSession()

                // Use a proxy as the delegate instead of the domain class.
                callable.delegate = new ClassProxy(delegate)
                callable?.call(session)

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("An error occured", e)
            } finally {
                session?.close()
                if(connection && !connection.closed) {
                    connection.close()
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here's the proxy:

```
// src/main/groovy/some/package/ClassProxy.groovy
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
/*
 * Create an instance of my like so: new ClassProxy(SomeClass)
 * and I will delegate method calls to the Class,
 * essentially converting instance method calls to Class static
 * method calls.
 */
class ClassProxy {
    Class clazz

    Object methodMissing(String name, Object args) {
        clazz.invokeMethod(name, args)
    }
}
```

`methodMissing()`, which is what dynamic finders depend on, works fine for instances, so the proxy takes advantage of this and simply invokes whatever method you call on it, on the real Class. In this case a domain class. I'm not sure if you need to change the default resolve strategy, but I don't think so. In my testing it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> ...otherwise groovy uses owner even though I've explicitly set the
>   closure resolve strategy to DELEGATE_FIRST.

I don't think that is correct.

You have the following:

```
callable.delegate = delegate
```

That is inside of the closure that you are assigning to `withDataSource`.

When you use `ExpandoMetaClass` in that way, the delegate of the closure will be the thing that you invoked the method on.  In your case, it will be the thing that you invoked `withDataSource` on.

Comment: Which is the domain class. `withDataSource` is added statically to domain classes and thus is invoked like so: `DomainClass.withDataSource(ds) { //do work }`. Since I invoked the metod on a domain class, by passing that delegate onto `callable` closure's delegate I'm hoping that it would implicitly use that class inside the closure, however unless i explicitly specify `delegate.withDataSource(ds) { //do work }` it seems to look within owner (that's what invocation exceptions tell me at least)

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck.